# Include typo3 LocalConfiguration.php

Tags: php, typo3

How can I include typo3's LocalConfiguration.php into my script (which is NOT inside typo3)? Since that file returns an array:

```
<?php
return [
    'BE' => [
    ...
```

I thought I have to put the include into a function:

```
function getConf() {
    include_once("typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php");
}
$conf = getConf();
print_r($conf);
```

but the output is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inlcude it directly to the variable:

```
$conf = include 'typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php';
```

Comment: You can do this, but should be aware that any number of additional files may be adding or changing configuration values from this file - so the result TYPO3 sees is very unlikely to be just the contents of that file. Other sources include but are not limited to AdditionalConfiguration.php (same place, written to by "lowlevel" config extension) and any ext_localconf.php file in any extension that is loaded.

Comment: That's correct @ClausDue. To get the correct configuration he should convert his script to an TYPO3 extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$GLOBALS` to read values from TYPO3 configuration, wich values are written/overwritten by these files in this order `DefaultConfiguration` + `LocalConfiguration` + `AdditionalConfiguration`

Comment: I only want to include that file and get the information, nothing more. I am not in typo3, I am in my own script, where no $GLOBALS variable is available.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you need to return the configuration:

```
<?php
function getConf() {
    return include_once("typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php");
}
$conf = getConf();
print_r($conf);
```

René Pflamm's solution should be easier